# appending negative sign to number in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel file in which for a particular column I have +/- sign numbers. like

```
123.32-
452.23
456.80-
```

When I am doing sum I am not getting the correct value.
How can bring the - sign to front so that I can get rite sum.

I want numbers be like

```
-123.32
452.23
-456.80
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: do it manually or write a macro. Show us your code!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Use this formula

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="-","-"&LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)*1
```

[image]

See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/42964/converting-a-number-with-minus-sign-on-right-to-minus-on-left) for details.

***EDIT :***

### Solution 2

This can be done without using formula also using `Text To Columns` feature, see [this](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/10/31/fix-numbers-with-trailing-minus-signs/).

- On the Excel Ribbon’s Data tab, click Text to Columns
- Click the Next button in Steps 1 and 2
- In Step 3, click the Advanced button
- Add a check mark to the option, "Trailing Minus for Negative Numbers"
- Click OK, and then click Finish

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposal:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1;1)="-";VALUE(LEFT(A1;LENGTH(A1)-1)*-1))
```

If you have `-` at the end, take the `A1` cell without the last sign. Then make it to `value` and multiply it by `-1` for negative. Thus, the result would be a number.

Comment: instead applying on every cell can't I apply on whole column?

Comment: @Khumar - Yes, if you know VBA.